# How to show that the indicator function of rationals (the Dirichlet function) is measurable?

Tags: probability-theory, functions, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

> Show that the function f : $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is measurable if $f(x)   \begin{equation}
>    =
>     \begin{cases}
>       1 & \text{if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$}\\
>       \\
>       0 & \text{if $x \notin \mathbb{Q}$}
>     \end{cases}       
> \end{equation}$.

Is the pre-image of f
$$\{ \omega \in \Omega : I_{\mathbb{Q}}(\omega)\in (-\infty, x]\}  \begin{equation}
   =
    \begin{cases}
      \emptyset & \text{if x < 0 }\\
      \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q} & \text{0 $\le$ x<1}\\
      \mathbb{R} & \text{x $\ge$ 1}
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}$$

and in that case, how do I use this to show that f is measurable?

Comment: There are many (equivalent) definitions of *measurable function* used in textbooks, lectures, and course notes. You should give the definition that you are using, otherwise some comments and answers you might later get will not be of much help.

Comment: The definition says:

Let $(\Omega_1, F_1)$ and $(\Omega_2, F_2)$ be two measurable spaces. A function $f : \Omega_1 \rightarrow \Omega_2 $ such that $$f^{-1}(B) = \{ x \in \Omega_1 : f(x) \in B \} \in F_1$$
for all $B \in F_2$, is called a measurable function.

Comment: You should put the definition from your comment into the body of your question.

Answer (score 1):

You are left to show that $\mathbb R$, $\emptyset$, and $\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$ are measurable.

The first two are obviously measurable, the $\sigma$-algebra of measurable sets must always include the full set and the empty set.

You are left to show that $\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$ is a measurable set, and for that you can first show that $\mathbb Q$ is measurable. But $\mathbb Q$ being countable, is a countable union of singletons, that is $\mathbb Q = \bigcup_{x\in \mathbb Q} \{x\}$. And singletons $\{x\}$ are obviously measurable (to show it you need to start from the definition of the sigma-algebra $F$ of measurable sets you use).

---

You can generalize the whole discussion to show the following very useful two facts:

- The indicator of a measurable set is always a measurable function.
- A countable set is always measurable.

Comment: Can I use the definition: 

"Let $(\Omega_1, F_1)$ and $(\Omega_2, F_2)$ be two measurable spaces. A function $f : \Omega_1 \rightarrow \Omega_2 $ such that $$f^{-1}(B) = \{ x \in \Omega_1 : f(x) \in B \} \in F_1$$
for all $B \in F_2$, is called a measurable function."
somehow? 

Since F is a sigma-algebra the empty set and full set will of course be in F like you said. But how do I show that $\mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q} \in F$?

Comment: Yes your question already hinted at your using this fact, and rightly so, so I took it for granted. Now my answer gave you a route to showing that R\Q is in F. Of course you have to start from what is F in your case (I guess it's the usual Borel $\sigma$-algebra).

Comment: I edited my answer slightly for clarity.